# React Installation problem npx-create-react-app not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, npm-install, npx

This is the error that Im facing every-time i do npx create-react-app app-name.
At first It was all good everything was working perfectly but all of a sudden it's been a few days since Im facing this error and i cant seem to solve it.

```
hassan_xiddiqui@Kratos:~/React$ npx create-react-app starter_1
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

Creating a new React app in /home/hassan_xiddiqui/React/starter_1.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hassan_xiddiqui/.npm/_logs/2021-04-03T12_14_14_243Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting starter_1/ from /home/hassan_xiddiqui/React
Done.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 2):

The error is very clear in the message you're receiving:

```
This is a problem related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

If you're using a VPS, disable it. Try checking your DNS settings, maybe change them to [Google's](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Also, try to install anything from NPM to confirm this is an issue with your connection.  `npm install -g create-react-app`. If this (or any other package) succeeds, it may be other issue.

Consider as well it could be an issue with `npx` on your machine. Try installing it using `create-react-app` directly instead by first installing it globally (like I showed above)

Comment: Hello, I even changed my whole OS for this shifted to Ubuntu from windows, still receiving this error I didn't even touched my DNS setting nor am I using any VPS still this is happening

Comment: Did you try installing anything like I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

It's more of an network error you can check the config or try to flush your dns or something. Maybe try some other network if possible

Comment: But how ? Im new to all this and I need an urgent fix I'll be very thankful to you If you can help me out

Comment: please don't urge for "urgent fixes" on StackOverflow, this is a forum of questions and answers, not a support one. Everyone is happy to help, but it's free help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install npm again using: `npm install`

Also check what node version you're using: `node --v`

Then, run the command again: `npx create-react-app app_name`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by updating my Windows 10